# If $B$ is an $A$-algebra of Noetherian rings then $\text{Ass}_{A}M=\{f^{-1}(p):p \in \text{Ass}_{B}M\}$ for a f.g. $B$-module $M.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, primary-decomposition

Let $A,B$ Noetherian rings and $f: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $B$ module. Then want to show that $\text{Ass}_{A}M=\{f^{-1}(p):p \in \text{Ass}_{B}M\}.$

So far I could prove that RHS is contained in the LHS. If $p \in \text{Ass}_{B}M$ then $p=(0:_{B}x)$ for some $x \neq 0$ in $M.$ Then clearly $f^{-1}(p)=(0:_{A}x).$ Now for the converse let $q=(0:_{A}z) \in \text{Ass}_{A}M$. Then clearly $f^{-1}(0:_{B}z)=q,$ but failed to show that $(0:_{B}z) \in \text{Spec(B)}.$ I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05DZ.

Comment: It really helps. Many thanks.